# I am trying to simulate a user login to Chegg but I am met with an access denied page

Tags: python, html, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I believe it may have something to do with the headers I have. Maybe I need to include more? Any help is greatly appreciated.

For those curious, I am doing this in order to get a Chegg answer by combining this code with the discord API.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Chegg account
2. While logged out, go to inspect element to access the developer console in a web browser
3. go to the network tab in the console
4. Go to the Chegg login page with the console open
5. In the network tab, find the login documentby choosing document type as XHR and searching for 'auth'
6. Go to the request section to see the headers.
7. Go to the very bottom to see the form data.

My current code in python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

EMAIL = config.USR
PASSWORD = config.PSWRD

URL = 'https://www.chegg.com/'
LOGIN_ROUTE = 'auth?action=login&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0', 'origin': URL, 'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

s = requests.session()

login_payload = {
        'email': EMAIL,
        'password': PASSWORD, 
        }

login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req.status_code)

cookies = login_req.cookies

soup = bs(s.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')

answer='answer.html'
with open(answer, "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

The HTML output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<title>Access to this page has been denied.</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #000;
        }

        a {
            color: #c5c5c5;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container > div {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .container > div > div {
            display: flex;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .customer-logo-wrapper {
            padding-top: 2rem;
            flex-grow: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .customer-logo {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .customer-logo > img {
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            max-height: 50px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .page-title-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 2;
        }

        .page-title {
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 5;
        }

        .content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .page-footer-wrapper {
            align-items: center;
            flex-grow: 0.2;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #c5c5c5;
            font-size: 70%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
<!-- Custom CSS -->
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
<div class="customer-logo-wrapper">
<div class="customer-logo">
<img alt="Logo" src=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-title-wrapper">
<div class="page-title">
<h1>Please verify you are a human</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="content">
<div id="px-captcha">
</div>
<p>
                Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the
                website.
            </p>
<p>
                This may happen as a result of the following:
            </p>
<ul>
<li>
                    Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
                </li>
<li>
                    Your browser does not support cookies
                </li>
</ul>
<p>
                Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking
                them from loading.
            </p>
<p>
                Reference ID: #6a688650-086b-11eb-9f07-b303a8506d58
            </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer-wrapper">
<div class="page-footer">
<p>
                Powered by
                <a href="https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked">PerimeterX</a>
                , Inc.
            </p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- Px -->
<script>
    window._pxAppId = 'PXzYvFOXaC';
    window._pxJsClientSrc = '//client.perimeterx.net/PXzYvFOXaC/main.min.js';
    window._pxFirstPartyEnabled = false;
    window._pxVid = '';
    window._pxUuid = '6a688650-086b-11eb-9f07-b303a8506d58';
    window._pxHostUrl = 'https://collector-PXzYvFOXaC.perimeterx.net';
</script>
<script>
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXzYvFOXaC/captcha.js?a=c&u=6a688650-086b-11eb-9f07-b303a8506d58&v=&m=0';
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    p.insertBefore(s, null);
    if (false) {
        s.onerror = function () {
            s = document.createElement('script');
            var suffixIndex = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXzYvFOXaC/captcha.js?a=c&u=6a688650-086b-11eb-9f07-b303a8506d58&v=&m=0'.indexOf('captcha.js');
            var temperedBlockScript = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXzYvFOXaC/captcha.js?a=c&u=6a688650-086b-11eb-9f07-b303a8506d58&v=&m=0'.substring(suffixIndex);
            s.src = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXzYvFOXaC/' + temperedBlockScript;
            p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
        };
    }
</script>
<!-- Custom Script -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to solve your problem by checking out the cookies but I think its not logging me in yet. I am trying to do something similar, if you want to talk about it just search @Ransom_s on telegram.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 import requests

 EMAIL = 'email'
 PASSWORD = 'password'

 URL = 'https://www.chegg.com/'
 LOGIN_ROUTE = 'auth?action=login&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F'

 HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 
 Firefox/42.0', 'origin': URL, 'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

 with requests.Session() as s:
    login_payload = {'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWORD}

    cookies = {'C':'0', 'CSessionID':'08a9eb14-e079-43d9-9324- 
    5bb2a1b67c57', 'O':'0', 'PHPSESSID':'m63rvb05b81ebq49t95lj2g5up', 'U':'0',
    'V':'3451f6bcadeab94adf9e9936a1c136a25f805cef923456.24539858',
    'exp':'A184B%7CA311A%7CA579C%7CA803B%7CC020A%7CP569C%7CP570C%7CP571C%7CA185C',
    'expkey':'8E1F75F3D4DF8937522F77DD4512176C', 'user_geo_location': "big data don't mind this"}`

   login_req = s.post(URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers = HEADERS, data = login_payload, cookies = cookies)
   login = s.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
   print(login_req.text)
```